# Angular binding width to ContentChildren

Tags: angular

I am trying to build a table component in Angular.

I have a [StackBlitz Demo Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4sdgtq)

When I try to bind width of a `<div>` to my column components i get 
`ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`

Is there a better way to achieve this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma620968816433166?file=src/table/offset-width.pipe.ts)

The first change detection cycle happens after `OnInit`. On that occasion, angular runs change detection to update the model and the view. Then it runs again at NgAfterViewInit and it doesn't expect any changes to happen on your template. What is changing is the width in your `TableComponent`. You can avoid it if you manage to delay the execution of the expression that change the width. One way of doing that that has come to me is using a pipe that returns an observable that can delay the emission of the width to change the property:

```html
<div class="cell" [style.width.px]="column | offsetWidth | async">-</div>
```

The `offsetWidth` pipe would be like this:

```
transform(column: ColumnComponent): Observable<string> {
    return of(1).pipe(
      delay(0), // <= this will delay the emision
      switchMap(_ => 
        of(column && column.elementRef.nativeElement.offsetWidth))
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated your Stackblitz with a private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef in the constructor, which now calls the detechChanges method in the ngOnInit lifecycle hook. Then you will not get any errors.

have look: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lvtprr?file=src/column/column.component.ts